# When published, format of date parameter in Pagianted Report changes from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a Paginated report which works fine. The date parameter changes from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy once it is published to PowerBI service. How to keep the date format in dd/mm/yyyy format even in PowerBi Service.

I changed the language setting to EN-SG.